# How to set password for Redis?

Tags: php, redis

I'm working with redis on my local machine  so I dont really need to set up a password to connect to the server with my php client (I'm using predis as a client). However, I'm moving my app to a live server, so I want to set up a password to connect to my redis server.

I have few questions:

- I checked all over the internet about how to set up the password and it looks like I need to add the password in the redis.conf. I couldnt find though what I should add exactly to the configuration file to set up the password.
- also in predis how should I add the password. I'm using the following array of parameters to connect to the redis server

  > $my_server = array('host'     => '127.0.0.1','port'     =>
  >   6379,'database' => 1);

should I add the password this way?

```
> $my_server = array('host'     => '127.0.0.1','port'     =>
> 6379,'database' => 1,'password'=>password);
```

- last question, I'm trying to stop my redis-server on the live server. Every time I enter the following command , I keep getting the same error message

  > redis-server stop
  >
  > [23925] 23 Sep 20:23:03 # Fatal error, can't open config file 'stop'

  usually on my local machine I enter

  > /etc/init.d/redis-server stop

to stop redis server but its not working on my live server since there is no process called redis-server in my /etc/init.d

Answer (score 183, accepted):

To set the password, edit your redis.conf file, find this line

```
# requirepass foobared
```

Then uncomment it and change foobared to your password.  Make sure you choose something pretty long, 32 characters or so would probably be good, it's easy for an outside user to guess upwards of 150k passwords a second, as the notes in the config file mention.

To authenticate with your new password using predis, the syntax you have shown is correct.  Just add password as one of the connection parameters.

To shut down redis... check in your config file for the `pidfile` setting, it will probably be

```
pidfile /var/run/redis.pid
```

From the command line, run:

```
cat /var/run/redis.pid
```

That will give you the process id of the running server, then just kill the process using that pid:

```
kill 3832
```

**Update**

I also wanted to add, you could also make the `/etc/init.d/redis-server stop` you're used to work on your live server.  All those files in /etc/init.d/ are just shell scripts, take the redis-server script off your local server, and copy it to the live server in the same location, and then just look what it does with vi or whatever you like to use, you may need to modify some paths and such, but it should be pretty simple.

Comment: This does not seem to work on Windows. I tried both conf files. I tried Redis restart in many combinations. The only thing that worked was: "redis-cli config set requirepass somepass". Additionally, every time server was restarted/shutdown, it was loosing password. So I guess, that's that with windows.

Comment: Depending on the chosen installation process we can have the Redis configuration file as "vi /etc/redis/redis.conf" or "vi /etc/redis/6379.conf" (eg) where "6379" is the value chosen for the port!

Comment: Is there a maximum password length?

Comment: Also, if the redis server is running, it prints out the pid at the top upon start... it should say Redis version=x.x.x bits=64, commit=xxxxxx, modified=0, pid=xxxx

Comment: Redis got better, machines become faster. Redis 6's config file states that "since Redis is pretty fast an outside user can try up to 1 million passwords per second against a modern box". It was 150K :-) I personally was using something like this `openssl rand 50 | openssl base64 -A` to generate a long password. However perhaps it is better to use ACL now.

Comment: @Jeffz *redis.windows-service.conf* is the config file you need to put your password in just like redis.windows.conf if you are running it as a service to keep authentication after redis restart

Comment: yeah just uncommenting that then restarting redis worked for me

Answer (score 107):

you can also use following command on client

**cmd ::** `config set requirepass p@ss$12E45`

above command will set `p@ss$12E45` as a `redis` server password.

Comment: Just to add: As mentioned at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_security.htm to login via redis-cli first get into the redis shell by running `redis-cli.exe`. Then type `AUTH <password>`.

Comment: And to disable password authentication, simply use `config set requirepass ""`

Comment: And it will reset to old if you restart redis. So, add in conf file as well.

Comment: Config set requirepass "myPassword" this command is not working for me, when I execute this command then it runs with no error. Then I restarted my Redis instance. But I can still ping to Redis instance from CLI without proving any password. Later I checked my redis.conf for requirepass attribute, there I found it in default state, which means config set requirepass command failed to set the value of requirepass in my config that's the reason it was not working. Any guess/reason why it is not working?

Comment: but you have to issue this after every server upstart. otherwise it wont bite, right? thats what   I am getting.

Answer (score 95):

Example:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH PASSWORD
(error) ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG SET requirepass "mypass"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH mypass
Ok
```

Comment: If one is using redis-py, the associated command is: `redis.Redis.config_set('requirepass', "mycoolpassword")`

Comment: Config set requirepass "myPassword" this command is not working for me, when I execute this command then it runs with no error. Then I restarted my Redis instance. But I can still ping to Redis instance from CLI without proving any password. Later I checked my redis.conf for requirepass attribute, there I found it in default state, which means config set requirepass command failed to set the value of requirepass in my config that's the reason it was not working. Any guess/reason why it is not working?

Comment: @AshishShukla how did you restart your Redis instance?

Comment: @LeaReimann in Linux you can use command -> sudo systemctl restart redis

Comment: this command won't work if you restart redis!

Answer (score 31):

using redis-cli:

```
root@server:~# redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG SET requirepass secret_password
OK
```

this will set password temporarily (until redis or server restart)

test password:

```
root@server:~# redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH secret_password
OK
```

Answer (score 30):

```
sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

find and uncomment line `# requirepass foobared`, then restart server

now you password is `foobared`

Answer (score 30):

For those who use `docker-compose`, it’s really easy to set a password without any config file like `redis.conf`. Here’s how you would normally use the official Redis image:

```
redis:
    image: 'redis:4-alpine'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

And here’s all you need to change to set a custom password:

```
  redis:
    image: 'redis:4-alpine'
    command: redis-server --requirepass yourpassword
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

Everything will start up as normal and your Redis server will be protected by a password.

For details, [this blog post](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-27-setting-a-password-on-redis-without-a-custom-config) seems to support the idea.

Comment: How does this know what user to use when other services wants to connect to Redis? Would it take the default or can you specify this on the commandline aswell?

Comment: Password for the “default” user is set in the configuration named “requirepass“

Answer (score 15):

open redis configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

set passphrase

replace

```
# requirepass foobared
```

with

```
requirepass YOURPASSPHRASE
```

restart redis

```
redis-server restart
```

Comment: If you are using redis as a service on Windows then you need to set password in **redis.windows-service.conf** file as well.

Answer (score 9):

1. stop redis server using below command

   ```
   /etc/init.d/redis-server stop
   ```
2. enter command: `sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf`
3. find  requirepass foobared word and remove # and change foobared to YOUR PASSWORD

ex. requirepass root

Answer (score 8):

On versions prior to REDIS 6 , the only way to secure your REDIS is to open your `redis.conf` , uncomment the `# requirepass` line, and add in your password. However , the downside of this is that this is a global password shared by ALL connections.

```
requirepass iampwd
```

Unless you need backwards compatibility you should move to REDIS 6, and instead use ACLs to create users with the least privileges

```
acl setuser dummyuser on >dummypwd allcommands allkeys
```

https://redis.io/topics/acl

Answer (score 6):

For Mac installed with HomeBrew/Brew (redis-cli):

```
redis-cli
AUTH oldpassword
CONFIG SET requirepass "newpassword"
CONFIG REWRITE
```

Restart:

```
brew services stop redis
//relogin
```

Answer (score 4):

For that, you need to update the redis configuration file.By default, there is no any password for redis.

01) open redis configuration file

```
sudo vi /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

find **requirepass** field under **SECURITY** section and uncomment that field.Then set your password instead of **"foobared"**

```
# requirepass foobared
```

It should be like,

```
requirepass YOUR_PASSWORD
```

Then restart redis and start redis-cli.

If you need to check whether you have set the password correctly, you can run below commads in redis-cli.

```
sithara@sithara-X555UJ ~ $ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set key1 18
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
127.0.0.1:6379> auth admin
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get key1
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> exit


sithara@sithara-X555UJ ~ $ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set key1 18
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
127.0.0.1:6379> auth admin
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set key2 check
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get key2
"check"
127.0.0.1:6379> get key1
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> set key1 20
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get key1
"20"
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

`

Answer (score 3):

This error means there is no password set in your redis instance. If you send auth information from your code you will probably get this message. There are two ways to solve.

1. Open the redis config file.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
   ```

   You can use 'where is' option to find '# requirepass'

   Uncomment the passphrase line and set new password

   ```
   # requirepass yourpassword
   ```
2. Open terminal and connect redis-cli

   ```
   redis-cli
   ```
3. Set passphrase

   ```
   CONFIG SET requirepass "yourpassword"
   ```
4. Finally, you can test

   ```
   AUTH yourpassword
   ```

Thats is!

Answer (score 2):

> i couldnt find though what i should add exactly to the configuration
>   file to set up the password.

Configuration file should be located at `/etc/redis/redis.conf` and password can be set up in SECURITY section which should be located between REPLICATION and LIMITS section. Password setup is done using the requirepass directive. For more information try to look at [AUTH](http://redis.io/commands/auth) command description.

Answer (score 2):

Run Command

```
redis-cli


redis 127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH PASSWORD
(error) ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG SET requirepass "amolpass"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH amolpass    
Ok
```

------------------OR ----------------------

Get Redis Installation Path

> redis-cli config get dir

GET Config File Path

```
sudo find / -name "redis.conf" -exec grep -H "^dir" {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

generate the same password as this one:

> echo "amol-pass" | sha1sum
> OUTPUT
> :960c3dac4fa81b4204779fd16ad7c954f95942876b9c4fb1a255667a9dbe389d

```
Edit : /etc/redis/redis.conf
requirepass 960c3dac4fa81b4204779fd16ad7c954f95942876b9c4fb1a255667a9dbe389d
```

Restart Redis

```
 service redis-server restart

 TEST Command : 
 redis-cli 
 set key1 10
 (error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
 auth your_redis_password
```

Answer (score 1):

## How to set redis password ?

step 1. stop redis server using below command
/etc/init.d/redis-server stop

step 2.enter command : sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf

step 3.find # requirepass foobared word and remove # and change foobared to YOUR PASSWORD

ex. requirepass root

Answer (score 0):

If you are losing password on Redis restart and you are running Redis as a windows service then you should set **requirepass** in **redis.windows-service.conf** file as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Machine

First Check Redis Status using the below command

`sudo systemctl status redis`

Now open the below file

`sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf`

In the Security Section, you can easily find the

`#requirepass foobared` 
[image: Befor_password_set_image_is]

Change that to whatever password you wanted to save for redis connection

`requirepass your_password or requirepass foobared`

Now your file section content looks like
[image]

Press Control + C, Control + Y & ENTER. The file will be saved now.

Now Restart the REDIS DB using the below Linux command

`sudo systemctl restart redis`

Now REDIS Password is SET SUCCESSFULLY .